# Convert Marker Image from v2 to API V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to convert the following code written for API v2

```
<!--- Add position and date information --->
var trackIcon = new GIcon({image:"/images/www2/icons/map_track_marker.png"});
trackIcon.iconSize = new GSize(6,6);
trackIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(3,3);
for (var i=0; i<trackArray.length;i++)
{
map.addOverlay(new GMarker(trackArray[i],{title:trackArrayInfo[i],icon:trackIcon}));
}
```

to V3, but without success. Here is my unsuccessful try:

```
<!--- Add position and date information --->
var trackIcon = new google.maps.Icon({image:"/images/www2/icons/map_track_marker.png"});
trackIcon.iconSize = new google.maps.Size(6,6);
trackIcon.iconAnchor = new google.maps.Point(3,3);                          
for (var i=0; i<trackArray.length;i++)
{
   new google.maps.Marker(trackArray[i], {title:trackArrayInfo[i],icon:trackIcon}).setMap(map);
}
```

Can anybody help me with this? I am getting hopeless :(

Answer (score 3):

The icon object doesn't have `image`, `iconSize`  or `iconAnchor`  properties in API v3.  Instead they're just `url`, `size` and `anchor`.

Also you need to assign the results of the new Marker to a variable.  I assume you're getting a JS error at this point, although it's not present in your question (could be useful if it were).

```
/* Add position and date information */
var trackIcon = new google.maps.Icon({
    url :"/images/www2/icons/map_track_marker.png",
    size : new google.maps.Size(6,6),
    anchor : new google.maps.Point(3,3)
});

for (var i=0; i<trackArray.length;i++)
{
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: trackArray[i],
          map: map, 
          title: trackArrayInfo[i], 
          icon: trackIcon
   });
}
```

Comment: I've tried to comment-out the .iconSize and .iconAnchor, but I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function " in console now.

Comment: I have this array filled with coordinates of markers for tracked devices trackArray[pos] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon)

Comment: thank you, it is really strange, it prints "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" into the console and map stays gray

Comment: You might want to give us the full JS code you're using, the error could be elsewhere

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem? I agree with duncan, the error is most likely elsewhere in your code (probably the map, but you may find it while creating the example).

Comment: We just need enough code to demonstrate the error you're experiencing, otherwise it might not be possible for us to solve your problem

Comment: I know, it is really stupid situation :) I've posted the code, which works. So I can move to other errors... I'm not happy camper with v2->v3 conversion..

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Add position and date information */
for (var i=0; i<trackArray.length;i++)
{
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: trackArray[i],
    map: map, 
    title: trackArrayInfo[i],                                        
    icon: "/images/www2/icons/map_track_marker.png",
    size: new google.maps.Size(6,6),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(3,3)
   });
}
```

it works like this. Thanks to @duncan for help!

Comment: You sure this works? Can't get anchor to actually change anchor.

Comment: Nvm. Love google map's api docs... Apparently it's at the moment called google.maps.MarkerImage instead of .Icon...

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else runs into the same related problem as me and googled his/her way her, it seems that in the current version (3.11) there's no `google.maps.Icon` but a `google.maps.MarkerImage` constructor. The previous answers would thus look like:

```
for (var i=0; i<trackArray.length;i++)
{
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: trackArray[i],
    map: map, 
    title: trackArrayInfo[i],                                        
    icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
      "/images/www2/icons/map_track_marker.png", // url
      new google.maps.Size(6,6), // size
      new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
      new google.maps.Point(3,3), // anchor
      new google.maps.Size(6,6) // resized size
    )
  });
}
```

It's not mentioned in the docs though so I'm not sure this is official in any way, but the official .Icon is gone and this works for me.

Comment: The `google.maps.MarkerImage` was deprecated and removed from the documentation.  After v3.10 it is replaced with [google.maps.Icon anonymous objects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#convertingtoicon)